# my svg file does not float right within the flex container

Tags: html, svg, flexbox

Hope someone can help with this one.
I have a flex container, it has 2 divs.
I need the first div to float left, and the second one (svg file) to float right.
The svg file displays under the first div.
not sure what to do...
enclosed, is my code...

```
<div class="middle-container flex-container">
      <div class="info">
        <h1 class="boldest">
        Find, hire & manage
        </h1>
        <p>
          Overpass provides
           a success
        </p>

        <<button type="button" name="button">email get started</button>

        <h5 class="faintest">
          Get started in minutes.
        </h5>
      </div>

        <div class="hero">
            <img  src="./images/hero.svg" alt="hero">
        </div>

    </div>
```

```
/* ******* middle container ****** */
.middle-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  align-items: start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  top: 0px;
}


.middle-container .info {

  float: left;

}
.middle-container .hero {
  float: right;

}
```

Also, this is the first line from the svg file

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="642.377" height="584.3" viewBox="0 0 642.377 584.3">
```

Answer (score 1):

`float` property won't apply inside `flex` elements. `flex` proposes its own solutions for aligning divs.

One of them is setting **auto margins**. In your case, for example, we can add `margin-left: auto` to the `.hero` div, and it will automatically push itself to the rightmost position of its parent.

You can check it at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckxvb027/)

**Sidenote:** the button element in your code has two brackets (`<<buton>`)